# How to get spinner's value even if user does not select value?

Tags: android

If the user does not select an item of the spinner how to get the default shown value of the spinner ?

Comment: Initially spinner selection like `spinner.setSelection(0);` then you can get like `spinner.getSelectedItem().toString()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For when it is clicked (selected something)

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
        Object item = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos);
    }
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    }
});
```

Or for what you want,

```
String Text = mySpinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
```